# What does it mean for a Metric to be complete?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I took a real analysis course recently and now that the class is over, I decided to go back and read some of the sections we skipped over. Right now I'm reading "Some Topological concepts in Metric Spaces" in Ross's Elementary Analysis.

They explained that a metric space $(S,d)$, where $S$ is the space and $d$ is the the metric, is *complete* if every Cauchy sequence in $S$ converges to some element in $S$.

There is a problem at the end of the section that defines two metrics, $d_1$ and $d_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and asks to:

> Show $d_1$ and $d_2$ are complete metrics on $\mathbb{R}^k$

I was wondering if there is a separate definition for a complete metric, or if the question is asking if $(\mathbb{R}^k, d_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^k, d_2)$  are complete.

If the latter is the case, is it proper language to ask if the metric itself is complete on a space rather than asking if the metric space is compete?

I realize this is probably a bit nit-picky, but I like to pay close attention to wording to avoid confusion.

Comment: It is indeed asking if $(\mathbb{R}^k,d_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^k,d_2)$ are complete spaces. When there is no confusion as to what set the metric is defined upon, then it is proper language. Particularly so if one speaks of  multiple distances on a fixed set. Recall that the distances are maps $d:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, so a metric by itself is already bound to a set (although we often abuse language when extending or restricting said metrics, like we use the "same" euclidean distance in $\mathbb{Q}$ as we do in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @DarthGeek a nitpick which is so small I'm ashamed of myself--but more correctly a fixed *set*, since $(X,d)$ and $(X,f)$ are regarded as different *spaces* if $d \neq f$, even if $X$ is fixed between them.

Comment: @ALB I stand corrected. I've edited the comment.

Comment: You can say either that (X,d) is a complete metric space or that d is a complete metric on X. They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metric space is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges in the space. A metric is complete if the metric space it generates is complete.